# Local website doesn't work on mobile browsers

Tags: android, mobile, browser, xampp, server

After lunching XAMPP localhost server, mobile browsers cannot access website but its working fine on other PC on network.

How can I solve it to run on mobile browsers?

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so please show it. And if you can't start with showing the url you use on that other pc and the one you use on mobile device.

Comment: No, its not programming question!!! I want to make local sites available on mobile not on PC's only! I'm using pc name to visit local website "http://iraqi-pc/(WebsiteName) its working on other PC's but not on mobiles! What I should to do?

Comment: How is the device connected to the LAN?

Comment: @greenapps Other devices connected by wireless

Comment: Use ip address of server instead.